# WPF RoutedCommand and CustomControl implementation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, custom-controls, routed-commands

I have a Window where I have a button and a CustomControl. When I click the button the CustomControl should do something (e.g. animate itself).

Here is code:

```
public static class Commands
{
    public static readonly RoutedCommand FooCommand = new RoutedCommand("Foo", typeof(MyCustomControl));
}

public class MyCustomControl : Control
{
    static MyCustomControl()
    {
      // Initialize as lookless control
      DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl)));

      // for some reason using typeof(MyCustomControl) doesn't seem to work. (not part of the same visual tree?)
      // typeof(UIElement) works, as button is a UIElement (?)
      //CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(MyCustomControl), new CommandBinding(Commands.FooCommand, OnFoo, OnCanFoo));
      CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(UIElement), new CommandBinding(Commands.FooCommand, OnFoo, OnCanFoo));
    }

    private static void OnFoo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // here I need to have the instance of MyCustomControl so that I can call myCustCtrl.Foo();
      Foo(); // <--- problem! can't access this
    }

    private static void OnCanFoo(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      e.CanExecute = true;
      e.Handled = true;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        // does this like:
        // this.Template.FindName(...
        // so this method can't be static
    }
}
```

and the XAML where I use the control:

```
<Window ...
  <!-- ... -->

<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Button Content="Do a foo!" Command="{Binding my:MyCustomControl.FooCommand}" />

<my:MyCustomControl Grid.Row="1">
    <!-- ... -->

    <!-- ... -->
</my:MyCustomControl>
</Grid>

<!-- ... -->
</Window>
```

The problem is in "OnFoo" method from MyCustomControl. This method is static and I need to access the method "Foo()" which is a method of MyCustomControl.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not cast the `sender` input parameter to an instance of your class?

```
private static void OnFoo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((MyCustomControl)sender).Foo();
}
```

Comment: That was my initial tought but it doesn't work because my sender is the button (System.Windows.Controls.Button).
And if I change the typeof to MyCustomControl in the constructor it disables my button.

Comment: Then look inside the `RoutedEventArgs` object...  the `MyCustomControl` may be in the `e.OriginalSource` property.

Comment: @juFo I've run into the same issue as you, and was wondering if you have a resolution? It's been a while since the issue was posted, but here is for hoping :)

Comment: I redesigned the app, so I didn't need this anymore. That was my quick solution :-)